# Associating user with login session in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm creating a project in VB.NET with a MySQL back end. The user logs in via a login system created in VB.NET and the users details are stored in the database.

I was just wondering theoretically how the user that logged in can be associated with that particular session through the life time of that session? I need this to happen so I can do further queries once the user has logged in which involves that user :)

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Answer (score 2):

Save the UserID in a Session Variable (Assuming that you have pulled the Users ID from the database, and it is stored in a variable I am calling userid):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserID", userid)
```

Then when you want to use it on any page (Assuming that you're userid is an Integer):

```
Dim userid as Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]
```

or in a Query String:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERID = " _
    + HTTPContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString() + ";"
```